# How to pass an array of <List> to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a list **ClaimData** in C# and it has three items Date, Type and Description
There can be multiple rows in this as below,

**ClaimData**

```
Date         Type      Description

01/02/2012  "Medical" "Its a medical"
05/02/2013  "Theft"   "Its a Theft"
01/02/2014  "Test"    "Its a Test"
```

I want to pass this whole data to a stored procedure in one go to the sql server, so that I can reduce the database hits. I have written stored procedure which can iterate through this list and insert them in a table.

How to achieve by manipulating the list object could be passed to the stored procedure as a parameter?

Comment: show us what you have done so far.

Comment: if you are using sql server 2008 use table value parameter.It is ideal for bulk insert and update both.refer this,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Miller, I know you want the code to better explain but sorry I have this object as of now. I am getting data in a C# List object. My question is just to know if there is any way we can better manipulate and pass the list object to a stored procedure. Once I get this list in the stored procedure, I can iterate through it and perform the necessary action as explained already by M.Ali below in answer section.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I sent all three column as a string using string builder and delimeter '|'

```
    DateString = '01/02/2012|05/02/2013|01/02/2014'
    TypeString = 'Medical|Theft|Test'
    DescString = "Its a medical|..."
```

On database side I used a function to delimit these strings and inserted all these values in a temp table. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to do a couple of things to get this going, since your parameter is getting multiple values you need to create a Table Type and make your store procedure accept a parameter of that type.

Since you are passing a `TABLE` as a parameter you will need to create a TABLE TYPE something as follows

**TABLE TYPE**

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ClaimData AS TABLE 
 (
    [Date]         DATE
    [Type]         VARCHAR(50)
    [Description]  VARCHAR(100)
  )
 GO
```

**Stored Procedure to Accept That Type Param**

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE mainValues 
 @TableParam ClaimData READONLY   --<-- Accepts a parameter of that type 
 AS                                  -- Note it is ReadOnly 
 BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

  --Temp table to store the passed values 
  -- since the passed parameter is only Read only and you
  -- cannot make any changes to the parameter so if you need to
  -- manipulate the data inside parameter you will need to get it
  -- into a Table vaiable.


  -- Declare a Table variable
  DECLARE @tmp_values table(
          [Date]         DATE
          [Type]         VARCHAR(50)
          [Description]  VARCHAR(100)
                            );   

   --Get values into that Table variable 
   INSERT INTO @tmp_values ([Date],[Type],[Description])
   SELECT [Date],[Type],[Description] FROM @TableParam

   -- Do other cool stuff with your passed data 

   SELECT * FROM @tmp_values  --<-- For testing purpose
END
```

**EXECUTE PROC**

Declare a variable of that type and populate it with your values.

```
 DECLARE @Table ClaimData(      --<-- Declare a variable of your type
          [Date]         DATE
          [Type]         VARCHAR(50)
          [Description]  VARCHAR(100)
                            ); 
 -- Populate the variable
   INSERT INTO @Table ([Date],[Type],[Description])
   SELECT [Date],[Type],[Description] FROM Source_Table

EXECUTE mainValues @Table   --<-- Stored Procedure Executed
```

Comment: How does he call that in C#?

Comment: Yes. Actually I want to pass the List array from C# code.